# How to convert decimals to these Ascii characters in matlab?

Tags: matlab, base64, data-conversion

I have a char with a bunch of decimals in each line from 0 to 63. I'm trying to convert these decimals to the one that represents it in the image below. So `0` should be changed to `A`, `1` should be changed to `B` and so on. Anyone know if there are some functions to make this easier in Matlab?

[image]

Comment: Your table isn't ASCII encoding of characters, so you can't use simple functions such as double( ) etc. You are probably going to have to write your own conversion function. I would suggest looking at the ismember( ) function using the 2nd Locb output. It would also help if you provided example inputs and desired outputs in your question so we know exactly what you want.

Comment: Your input is a char array, not a numeric array? You'll have to convert those strings to numbers first, then do a table lookup (but remember MATLAB indexing starts at 1!).

Comment: The table indicates that the 0 to 63 values are represent with only 6 bits. This looks like you're trying to do Base64 encoding – is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

E.g. start with this char string:

```
S = ['A':'Z','a':'z','0':'9','+','/']
```

Then you can use this for mapping back & forth between the numbers and the characters, offsetting the index by 1. E.g.,

```
c = 'THEstring'
[~,N] = ismember(c,S); % From char string to numbers
x = N-1 % Offset by 1
C = S(x+1) % From numbers back to char string, offset by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is some missing context to your question because this looks a lot like [base64 encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). If that is the case, then to implement this properly, groups of three bytes (24 bits) are encoded by four 6-bit Base64 key values. For example, three 8-bit values such as `uint8(0:2)` are represented as `00000000` `00000001` `00000010` in binary. These can then be split into four 6-bit values, `000000` `000000` `000100` `000010`, which, per your table, results in `'AAEC'`.

Luckily, Matlab has built-in functions encode/decode Base64 with [`matlab.net.base64encode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.base64encode.html) and [`matlab.net.base64decode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.base64decode.html). These include padding with `'='` for cases where the number of inputs bytes is not divisible by three. My example above can be replicated with:

```
V = uint8(0:2);
res = matlab.net.base64encode(V)
matlab.net.base64decode(res) % convert result back
```